# bash: check if file or symlink (even dangling) exists?

Tags: bash

I need to check if a file exists in bash.  The `-e` is not working for a dangling symlink.

In this case I copied `ld-linux.so.2` to another directory.  The relative link points to `i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so` which doesn't exist.

When I run this (from the directory `ld-linux.so.2` is in):

```
if [[ -e ld-linux.so.2 ]]; then  echo "yes"; fi
```

The result is nothing prints which suggests that `-e` is checking the target and not the symlink itself.   How can I just check if the file exists, not the file it points to?

TIA!!

Comment: If searching files only: Use `-f` instead of `-e`. It follows sym links and analyze the linked file. So soft links to e.g. a directory are false.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-h` to test if a symlink exists:

```
if [[ -h ld-linux.so.2 || -e ld-linux.so.2 ]]; then  echo "yes"; fi
```

Comment: I prefer `-L`, sounds better with symLink.